# google buzz php api to store multiple buzz accounts and post to all accounts

Tags: php, accounts, google-buzz

I have an application where i want to integrate multiple buzz accounts to the one site. So that when i publish something on the site i want it to go to all the buzz accounts.
Is this possible?? If possible then can anybody provide some example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you can't do this in a single request.  But you can certainly perform multiple calls to the [Buzz API](http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/docs/), one for each profile you want the content to be posted to.  An example of creating a post using the [Buzz PHP Library](http://code.google.com/p/buzz-php-client/) can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/buzz-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/createPostSimple.php).

Alternately, you could simply setup the site as a [connected site](http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/docs/connect.html) on each of the Google accounts, and let the content flow in that way.  You could additionally use [PubSubHubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) on your site to have the content arrive into Buzz in real-time if you want.